# How to import classes when copy-paste in InteliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, import, annotations, gradle

I want to ***copy-paste*** some annnotation declarations from one class to another and for this annotations I have to make some imports, so InteliJ ask me
[image]

But if I click OK then the imports are added as:

[image]

But I want to add them as in Eclipse in the top where the other imports are:
[image]

How I can do this with when ***copy-paste*** with InteliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not that IntelliJ cannot add these imports but because your IntelliJ project does not have Gradle core JAR (the one containing `org.gradle.api` packages) on its classpath. Once you fix your project setup copy&paste should work as expected.

Comment: I add Gradle's jars and it works, but IneliJ use Gradle for building the project why it doesn't find the libs which use for building?

Comment: 1. Your build system is not part of your project dependencies (you do not expect to see Ant classes when building Ant project similarly as you should not have Gradle classes on compile classpath when building with Gradle). Non-intuitively Eclipse project can add Gradle classes to its classpath to provide code completion when editing `.gradle` files.
2. Can you show us your `build.gradle`? It seems strange that IJ does not import your project dependencies correctly.

Comment: apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
    compile gradleApi()
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
   ...
}

Comment: Interesting. With a build script like this you should have all the Gradle libraries on classpath when you import the project into IntelliJ.

Comment: I created the project from begining in InteliJ I do not import it. Do I have to apply 'idea' plugin and to run task 'idea'?